# PHP - Mysql blob to image

Tags: php, html, mysql, blob

I've read many posts but for some reason it still doesn't work. As in the title, I want to display image in the website which is stored in `MySQL` as `MEDIUM BLOB`. Here is the code which uploads the image:

```
if (isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"])) {
    if(getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]) == FALSE)
        echo '<p style="color: red" >No file selected</p>';
    else {
        echo '<p style="color: red" >SELCETED</p>';
        $image= addslashes($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['tmp_name']);
        //$imageName= addcslashes($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['name']);
        $image = file_get_contents($image);
        $image = base64_encode($image);
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['trescText']) )
    $trescText=$_POST['trescText'];

if($titleText != ""&& $trescText != "") {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO blog (title,cykl,tresc, image) VALUES('$titleText','$cyklText','$trescText','$image')");
    $stmt->execute();
    header('Location: addPost.php');
}

$conn->close();
```

And the code which displays it:

```
<?php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT image FROM blog WHERE id='98'");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($image);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    // echo '<img src="data:image;base64,'$image' "/>';
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image) .'" />';
}
?>
```

The problem is that instead of orginal image I get this:

[image]

Comment: You base64 encode the image twice, once when inserting it into the database, once when sending it to the browser.

Comment: Apart from that a warning: your code is _mile wide open_ to sql injection attacks...

Comment: @arkascha: Answers don't go in the comments.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition That is not a full answer in my eyes, I just hint to the cause. That is why it certainly should be a comment. A full answer should contained fixed code.

Comment: @arkascha: No, comments are for requesting clarification and critiquing the post. Providing technical solutions in the comments section is wrong, as you bypass the entire peer review system that serves as the foundation of this website. (_"A full answer should contained fixed code."_ This is debateable too; this is not a personal helpdesk or free consultancy service. Teach a man to fish.) If you are not ready to write a full answer, you can leave it to someone who is! Thanks.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Sure Mr. Policeman. Thanks for protecting the world from my evil doings.

Comment: @arkascha: You're welcome!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Thanks! You really made my day a fun one!

Comment: @arkascha: And there are still so many hours left! Imagine the fun we could have :)

Comment: @arkascha: What would you suggest to prevent these injection attacks?

Comment: Well, doing what is documented for that. Start reading about the advantages of using "prepared statements" in combination with "parameter binding".

Comment: @arkascha: Could you support me with any links?

Comment: I suggest you start reading the documentation of the tool you use: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @arkascha: Great! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You base64-encoded it twice: once when inserting it into the database, and again when sending it to the browser.

Base64-encoding has a tangible result; that is, it transforms the data. It is not temporary. The data in your database are the base-64 representation of your image's bytes, and that's the same data that you pull out later with `SELECT`.

So you only want to do the encoding once.